# Is there a way divide canvas in two sections?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I want to create a design like the image below. I was thinking about using two canvas for each drawing and merging them somehow. In the end, I need both of them to act like a single canvas because I am trying to stream the canvas using webRTC. I have tried drawing two canvas into a third canvas.

> ```
> const ctx = canvas1.getContext("2d"); //600/500 pixels
> const ctx2 = canvas2.getContext("2d"); //600/100 pixels
> const contex = canvas.getContext("2d"); //final canvas 600/600 pixels
>
> contex.drawImage(canvas1, 0, 0); //canvas 1 in image
> //contex.clearRect(0, 500, 600, 100);
> contex.drawImage(canvas2, 0, 500); //canvas 2 is the counter
> ```

The problem I have is that each count is drawing over each other in the final canvas.

[image]

Comment: You need to clear the canvas area where the number is before drawing the new number. Does your canvas2 have only the number or the green box too?

Comment: @tom both numbers and the rectangle

Comment: I put clearRect right before where the number in being drawn. Didnt work

Comment: I also put clear react in the final canvas and cleared the green box only. Works like a charm. Thankyou